# Developing Efficient Layouts

Tags: android, xml

I've just discovered `layout_column` and `layout_span`.

Currently, I use `layout_weight`, or plain old `layout_width="dp"`.

Can someone please explain the most efficient/popular/useful syntaxes? I feel like I'm always going to discover new syntax and want to re-write my layout code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

layout_column and layout_span both are attributes of Table Layout. You can only use them in Table layout

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="some text"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:text="some text"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="some other text" 
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:layout_span="1" />
        <TextView android:text="more text" 
            android:padding="3dip" 
            android:layout_span="4"/>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

In above xml both rows take the same space , the only difference is that in row one Textview and EditText are in ratio 2:3 and in second row both TextViews are in ration 1:4 in terms of space occupied by them.

**Layout Coloumn** simply means the index of the column in which this child should be .Also one thing to keep in mind is that columns start at index 0.

The best layout at present is Relative Layout , thats what i recommends because it saves a lot of lines of code and it also avoids nesting of layout also do avoid un-necessary nesting of layout. Weight concept is fool-proof concept to make complex layouts, if used weight wisely you have made your risk factor to 0%.

Answer (score 0):

There are no big ideas behind layout attributes, it's more a practical thing. I would study as many existing screens as possible so I know how people do that. I would start at SDK examples.